# How do I adjust the values ​of the y-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm having troubles with the y-axis values of this plot. I don't know how to adjust the y-axis values to get a plot more "relaxed" (Idk how to explain it)

[image]

The code is

```
     \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
          \usepackage[a4paper, margin = 1 in]{geometry}
          \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
           \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
         \usepackage{pgfplots}
         \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
                  \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[


                     title = {Gráfico de Sedimentación},
                        %scale only axis,
                        axis lines = left,
                        xlabel = {Número de componente},
                        ylabel = {Autovalor},
                        xmin=0, xmax=5,
                        ymin=0, ymax=4,
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
                        ytick={3.395,1.059,0.410,0.110,0.027},
                        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3},
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style = dashed,
                    ]

                    \addplot[
                        color=black,
                        mark = *,
                        ]
                        coordinates {(1,3.395) (2,1.059) (3,0.410) (4,0.110) (5, 0.027)};

                    \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would make it a logarithmic plot.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymode=log,
   title = {Gr\'afico de Sedimentaci\'on},
      %scale only axis,
      axis lines = left,
      xlabel = {N\'umero de componente},
      ylabel = {Autovalor},
      xmin=0, xmax=5,
      ymin=0, ymax=4,
      xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
      ytick={3.395,1.059,0.410,0.110,0.027},
      yticklabels={3.395,1.059,0.410,0.110,0.027},
      yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3},
      ymajorgrids=true,
      grid style = dashed,
      ylabel style={yshift=1em}
  ]

  \addplot[
      color=black,
      mark = *,
      ]
      coordinates {(1,3.395) (2,1.059) (3,0.410) (4,0.110) (5, 0.027)};

 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you want to keep your plot, use `nodes near coords`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%ymode=log,
   title = {Gr\'afico de Sedimentaci\'on},
      %scale only axis,
      axis lines = left,
      xlabel = {N\'umero de componente},
      ylabel = {Autovalor},
      xmin=0, xmax=5,
      ymin=0, ymax=4,
      xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
      ytick={3.395,1.059,0.410,0.110,0.027},
      yticklabels={},
      yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3},
      ymajorgrids=true,
      grid style = dashed,
      ylabel style={yshift=1em},
      nodes near coords
  ]

  \addplot[
      color=black,
      mark = *,
      ]
      coordinates {(1,3.395) (2,1.059) (3,0.410) (4,0.110) (5, 0.027)};

 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is a good option, but relevant information is lost

Comment: @MijailLittin What do you mean by "relevant information is lost". IMHO it is the opposite, you show that the data has an approximately exponential dependence on the number of components, and can even read off the slope.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. I mean, the curve changes. Now, it looks almost like a straight line

Comment: @MijailLittin Yes, because it is a logarithmic axis. Exponentials look like straight lines in a logarithmic axis. This is precisely the point, and which is why they are used.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Sorry, my english is not good. I want to keep the exponential curve, is it possible?

Comment: @MijailLittin In this case I recommend `nodes near coords`, see the update.